# Incorrect syntax near 'real'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm creating a creating a marksheet on winforms using sql server2008 to store the numbers, percentage etc to database.. however i'm getting the above exception error while using this below code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float a = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            float b = float.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            float c = float.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            float d = float.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            float f = float.Parse(textBox5.Text);
            float g = (a + b + c + d + f);
            float h = (g / 500) * 100;
            label11.Text = Convert.ToString((g));
            label14.Text = Convert.ToString(h + "%");
            label11.Visible = label14.Visible = true;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Emmad-PC;Initial Catalog=SchoolManagement;User ID=sa;Password=lenovo");
            SqlCommand j =new SqlCommand("Insert into Marksheet(RollNo, English, Math, Science, PSt, Islamiat, Total, Percentage) where values(@ROLL NO, @English, @Math, @Science, @Pakistan Studies, @Islamiat, @Total, @Percentage",con);
            j.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROLL NO",float.Parse(textBox6.Text));
            j.Parameters.AddWithValue("@English", float.Parse(textBox1.Text));
            j.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Math", float.Parse(textBox2.Text));
            j.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Science", float.Parse(textBox3.Text));
            j.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pakistan Studies", float.Parse(textBox4.Text));
            j.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Islamiat", float.Parse(textBox5.Text));
            j.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total",Convert.ToString( label11.Text));
            j.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percentage",Convert.ToString(label14.Text));

            con.Open();
            j.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

your suggestion will be highly appreciable :)

Comment: As others have said, you should remove the `where`, what was you intent when you wrote it?

Comment: Aside from the other comments you have a couple other issues here. The first is your table seems horribly denormalized. And second is you are using floats to store grades. The float datatype is approximate and shouldn't be used when exact values matter. In this case probably an int or numeric would be a better choice. Last but not least, your Total column should be a computed column so you don't get the value out of synch with the other column values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *multiple* things wrong with this query:

```
Insert into Marksheet
  (RollNo, English, Math, Science, PSt, Islamiat, Total, Percentage)
where values
  (@ROLL NO, @English, @Math, @Science, @Pakistan Studies, @Islamiat, @Total, @Percentage
```

1. You have an extra `WHERE` keyword for no reason.  (Remove it)
2. You *might* be using some reserved words in those column names.  (Enclose them in `[]` to explicitly define them as identifiers and not keywords)
3. You have whitespace in your parameter names.  (Remove it)
4. You didn't close the parentheses.  (Close it)

Here:

```
INSERT INTO [Marksheet]
  ([RollNo], [English], [Math], [Science], [PSt], [Islamiat], [Total], [Percentage])
VALUES
  (@ROLLNO, @English, @Math, @Science, @PakistanStudies, @Islamiat, @Total, @Percentage)
```

And, of course, update the parameter-adding lines for the corrected parameter names:

```
j.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROLLNO",float.Parse(textBox6.Text));
j.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PakistanStudies", float.Parse(textBox4.Text));
```

Additional suggestions, while we're on the subject:

1. `AddWithValue()` works, but [isn't always the best idea](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).  It relies on the system figuring out the type for you, and it's not always correct.  Explicitly setting the type when adding the parameter has less potential for bugs.
2. `float.Parse()` has potential for exceptions depending on the user input.  Parse the values first, using `float.TryParse()`, before trying to use them in a database interaction.  Once they're parsed successfully, *then* move on to the database part of the code.
3. (Well, "2A." actually...) You're parsing the values *twice* and just ignoring the first variables for some reason.
4. Make use of the `using` statement to enclose the usage of any `IDisposable` objects.  (In this case mainly your `SqlConnection` object.)  There's less risk of errors and resource leaks since it generates a `finally` block and handles closing/disposing the connection for you.
5. You don't need to call `Convert.ToString()` on a `string` value.  It's already a string.

Comment: Also `AddWithValue` shouldn't be used since [it *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @SonerGönül: True, explicit typing is probably a good idea in this case as well.

Comment: And don't forget to mention `using` statement to dispose connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually :)

Comment: ok.. i have removed where keyword but i have still having problem in it :/

Comment: @SyedEmmadZia: Can you be more specific?  I can't see your screen from here, so you'll have to actually describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the WHERE keyword, it is incorrect to use it in an insert statement.